# MC34063 Step Up regulator output voltage too high

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I have a wall wart which is rated for 12V-2A, but I noticed that the voltage drops to 9V when I put a load of 500mA. To get a steady 12V on output I am trying to build a regulator using MC34063. I am using the chip in step up mode and calculated the values of components required using Vmin as 9V, Vf as 0.4V and Vsat as 0.45.

Now the problem is that the output I am getting is around 21V steady. When I put load the voltage starts fluctuating between 21V and 18V.

Following are the component values:

```
Rsc = 0.5ohm
R1 = 59kohm
R2 = 540kohm
CT = 100pF
Co = 100uF
Cin = 100uF
L = 47uH
```

I have checked the circuit multiple times and evryting looks good. The voltage at pin 5 between the voltage divider is around 3V which I feel is strange for inverting input but follows the output.

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this on a breadboard? I suggest soldering everything before you fry the chip (yes, it can happen if the capacitors become loose). Also the Rsc looks suspiciously high for 500 mA output. Also, a wallwart that gives 500 mA at 9V is never never never ever ever going to give you 500 mA at 12 V.... just something to consider.

Comment: Yes this is on a breadboard. I will solder everything on a perfboard and check.

Comment: I suggest wearing a mask and making the trip. Get a 24V supply if you are desperate to use the MC34063. That way you won't have to return it if it can't deliver 500 mA at 12 V.

Comment: Design a PCB for it with a good ground plane.

Comment: A 12 V, 2A adapter shouldn't drop to 9 V at 500 mA. It means the adapter has a **crappy** design or is broken. Why would you waste your time with a boost converter? Realize that a boost converter draws **more current** at its input than it delivers at its output. (9 V, 500 mA would, without losses, coverts to 12 V, 375 mA) so you would be asking **even more current** from that crappy adapter. Also note that above ~100 mA, **breadboards don't work very well**, this is due to contact resistance etc.

Comment: Also, whenever I need a boost converter, even though I have all the skills and experience to design my own, I just **buy a module** (yes, a cheap one from China), building your own is such a waste of time, unless you want to make a career of designing DCDC converter PCBs of course.

Comment: I agree with above, input cap ESR and source impedance of wall-wart can negatively affect regulation as well as DCR and boost startup surge currents. Even the earliest PC designs had over voltage stability issues without a 10% preload, overcome with better designs now.